# Advanced search by title doesn't filter on the title

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, api-v2.1

Searching by title on the [advanced search method](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search) doesn't restrict the results to posts containing the specified text as a word or even substring. Varying the string has some influence, but I can't figure out what.

https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/search/advanced?order=desc&sort=creation&title=gobbledygook&site=stackoverflow (excerpted):

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "question_id": 11639593,
      "last_edit_date": 1343165944,
      "creation_date": 1343165332,
      "last_activity_date": 1343165944,
      "score": 0,
      "answer_count": 0,
      "title": "UILabel does not display all the text",
      "tags": [
        "objective-c",
        "ios",
        "uilabel"
      ],
      "view_count": 10,
      "owner": {
        "user_id": 1418175,
        "display_name": "Kamran Pirwani",
        "reputation": 12,
        "user_type": "registered",
        "profile_image": "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/477769b38fa65ab070a14d29e61c81ef?d=identicon&r=PG",
        "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/users/1418175/kamran-pirwani"
      },
      "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11639593/uilabel-does-not-display-all-the-text",
      "is_answered": false
    },
    {
      "question_id": 11639592,
      "last_edit_date": 1343165816,
      "creation_date": 1343165332,
      "last_activity_date": 1343165816,
      "score": 0,
      "answer_count": 0,
      "title": "no packages or platforms in sdk manager",
      "tags": [
        "android",
        "eclipse",
        "eclipse-adt"
      ],
      "view_count": 13,
      "owner": {
        "user_id": 1549903,
        "display_name": "tasneem radwan",
        "reputation": 1,
        "user_type": "registered",
        "profile_image": "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/97b31c0b552572afceca5f5a4b244d90?d=identicon&r=PG",
        "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/users/1549903/tasneem-radwan"
      },
      "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11639592/no-packages-or-platforms-in-sdk-manager",
      "is_answered": false
    },
    {
      "question_id": 11639585,
      "creation_date": 1343165311,
      "last_activity_date": 1343165311,
      "score": 0,
      "answer_count": 0,
      "title": "C++ /cli Marshal, String^ to std::string",
      "tags": [
        "string",
        "c++-cli",
        "marshalling",
        "std"
      ],
      "view_count": 5,
      "owner": {
        "user_id": 1492812,
        "display_name": "user1492812",
        "reputation": 39,
        "user_type": "registered",
        "profile_image": "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8c53bd1c4cfa23b278fd611c982be08c?d=identicon&r=PG",
        "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/users/1492812/user1492812",
        "accept_rate": 25
      },
      "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11639585/c-cli-marshal-string-to-stdstring",
      "is_answered": false
    },
…
```

https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/search/advanced?order=desc&sort=creation&title=process&site=stackoverflow returns a different set of questions (none of them with “process” in the title). On the other hand, https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/search/advanced?order=desc&sort=creation&title=algorithm&site=cs and https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/search/advanced?order=desc&sort=creation&title=helloworld&site=cs return identical results (which from a cursory inspection seem to be the most recent questions on the site).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed in the latest deploy (it also affected `body` turns out).

We've got some changes to our search infrastructure in the pipeline, and API v2.1 is being used to test them out.  You might have noticed it's had some... issues.  Better to find them in an API beta than after the rollout to the Q&A sites though.